# Python join floats to string - 'unicode' object is not callable

Tags: python, string, unicode

I write code in python

```
for cord in cords:
   s += str(cord[0]) + ' ' + str(cord[1])
```

where:
cords is 10k 2 float elements array (cords[[1.1, 1.2], [1.3, 5.2], ...]) and s is string ('')

i want to join all cords elements in one string like this:
s = '(5.25 53.23), (1.52 5.25), (...)';

but i have error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "script.py", line 24, in 
>       s += str(cord[0]) + ' ' + str(cord[1])
>   TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable

How to join float`s to one string?

Comment: You've probably called a local variable `str` somewhere, so it's shadowing the built-in type.

Comment: @DanielRoseman http://i.imgur.com/gdkaI.jpg

Comment: @Cyber no, I've just been hanging around here a *long* time.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Are you sure its hanging and not floating...  Wizards don't hang... do they ?

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same problem in my script. 
I tried everything including setting environment variable "PYTHONIOENCODING" to 'utf-8', but did not work since the problem was not that.

Like [goggelj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1176660/goggelj) said above, my problem was using "**str**" as a variable in my code. 
I changed my "**str**" variable and my problem solved.

Thanks goggelj.

Answer (score 1):

check that you do not have a local variable called str somewhere. If you do, python will assume you are trying to do something with it.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked fine for me.

```
cords = [[1.1, 1.2], [1.3, 5.2]]
s = ""
for cord in cords:
    s += "("+str(cord[0]) + ',' + str(cord[1])+")"
print s
```

Answer (score 0):

Does

```
s += '%s %s'%(cord[0],cord[1]) #insert spaces in middle
```

throw up the same error?

Its a simpler way of string formatting, that helps in getting it however you want, eg.

```
s += '(%s , %s)'%(cord[0],cord[1])
```

to get the (a.n , e.j) style.